# Bound Child By Height of Parent + Parent Pseudo Element

Tags: html, css

I have a div with a triangle as a pseudo element on top, and an image inside of this div, as you can see in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sc7dngy6/). I am trying to make the image contained within the bounds of the parent with the pseudo element, so that the image extends all the way through the triangle.

However, I am not sure how to do this. I have tried a few ways, including skewing the container etc but have not managed to create an elegant, responsive solution.

Please give me your suggestions if possible.

Edit: I am trying to make the image look like the following:

[image]

e.g. the ring is quite large and simply gets cut off by the containing element.

```css
.bg {
  background: black;
  color: white;
  position: relative;
  filter: drop-shadow(0 0 3vh rgba(30, 14, 43, 1));
  height: 20vh;
  width: 100vw;
  margin: 30vh 0;
}   

.bg::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  display: block;
  border-bottom: 18vh solid black;
  border-right: 12vw solid transparent;
  border-left: 88vw solid transparent;
}

.ring {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;   
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.container {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class='bg'>
  <div class='container'>
    <img src='http://pngimg.com/uploads/jewelry/jewelry_PNG6788.png' class='ring'>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think you'd be better off using `clip-path`..

Comment: @Paulie_D can you show me what you mean pls?

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/clipping-masking-css/

Answer (score 0):

You may try to have the shape as one element and consider some rotation transform and `overflow:hidden` :

*go full page for better result*

```css
  body {
  margin: 0;
}

.bg {
  color: white;
  position: relative;
  height: 90vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: right;
}

.container {
  position: absolute;
  filter: drop-shadow(0 0 3vh rgba(30, 14, 43, 1));
  height: 160%;
  transform: rotate(-20deg);
  top: 42%;
  left: -2%;
  right: -4%;
  background: #000;
  overflow: hidden;
}

img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 15%;
  left: 61%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(20deg);
  ]
```

```html
<div class='bg'>
  <div class="container">
    <img src='http://pngimg.com/uploads/jewelry/jewelry_PNG6788.png' class='ring'>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, however, the ring is not contained within the bounds of both elements; when I copy into jsfiddle the ring ends up outside. I really need it such that the pseudo element contains the overflow of the top of the ring.

Comment: @annikam yes as you need to adjust values :) i simply did a quick example, but adjusting some values will make the images stay always inside the shape (as you can see here it's inside)

Comment: @annikam i made more update to make it always stay in the shape ;)

Comment: Temani, thank you for your help, but please see my edit. I think your solution doesn't actually bound the element but rather requires you to place it such that it is bounded. What I am looking for is to be able to change the size of the image dynamically and always have it bounded.

Comment: @annikam oh i see, didn't understand it this way :) ok am gonna update my code

Comment: @annikam check my answer again ;)